# scala: directed and undirected edges of Graphs

Tags: scala, graph, directed-graph, undirected-graph

If a directed Edge is implemented something like:

```
class EdgeImpl(origin: Node, dest: Node) {
    def from = origin
    def to = dest
  }
```

then which is the difference for implementing an `undirected Edge` while when we create a new `Edge` we also have to say in both cases: `new EdgeImpl(node1, node2)`? I do not get the difference in implementation :(

### Edit

I was analyzing, more concretely, this [example](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html)

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't implement an undirected graph the same way. If you wanted, you could make it more explicit by adding each edge twice: `new EdgeImpl(node1, node2); new EdgeImpl(node2, node1)`. Note that graphs are among the most-used data structures in computer science, so there are a lot of different implementations with different strengths and weaknesses. Maybe you could clarify your question, as I do not fully get what you are asking.

Comment: @Kulu Limpa, I cannot be more specific while I am trying to understand all pieces that are mandatory/needed to model a graph in code. But your comment is very helpfull to understand a piece of it. Thankss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference in the implementation of an Edge, in both cases just the two connected nodes need to be specified.

The difference would pop-up when you wanted to implement something else where the meaning of an edge needs interpretation. For instance, if you had a method `areConnected(a: Node, b: Node): Boolean`, then its implementation would traverse the list of edges and, if in a directed graph would return true if `from == a && to == b`. The undirected version would evaluate `(from == a && to == b) || from == b && to == a)` instead.

That example is kind of convoluted and does not make clear why the features described are really needed, but consider for instance how you would go creating a WeightedDirectedGraph, where each edge also contains a weight or distance between the connected nodes.

Comment: ,Thanks a lot. It's a great explanation because I was thinking that I do not need to care for `from-to` in the undirected graph at all as it is more general than the directed one :(

Comment: It is more general, in fact, you can create an undirected graph with a directed one where each link is added twice (with opposite directions), but that wastes memory for no reason. The choice of course, really depends on what you are trying to model.